# Google Cloud hard quota limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been trying for a while to figure out if Google Cloud has a mechanism for a "crowbar" limit on API usage, as a security measure.

The scenario I'm concerned about is, say I have an API keyfile on a server, and a hacker steals it and plugs it into their system that (for the purposes of some nebulous scam) is running an unbounded number of translate requests as quickly as possible. I then receive a $25,000 bill. I don't see any mechanisms to really prevent this.

I can limit the roles for that key, but if the hacker's interest is in the same API I use for my project, that doesn't help. I can set a billing limit, but that just sends me an email, and I am not a person who notices incoming email, so in practice it would take me days to realize this had happened.

I can set a quota, but all the quotas in the dashboard seem to be per-minute or per-day limits. I need a per-*month* quota, and I don't see any way to do it. Am I just missing something, or does Google simply provide no option for this?

I understand that "well just don't let your API key get compromised" is probably the common wisdom, but that's unacceptable to my use cases for a number of reasons, so I'm not interested in discussing it. Thanks!

Edit: I should note, Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) says "you can set requests per day caps" - but there are no instructions on that page for how to do this, and I can see no mechanism for it. I don't want a per-day cap, I want a per-month cap, but I'd take a per-day cap if I could find one. These are the only quotas I see for Cloud Vision, for instance:

[Quotas part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oMRW.png)

[Quotas part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhyZe.png)

Comment: So, in my work, how i try to counter these sort of issues is - limit the roles to keys, and then alerting on bill payments, you can set threshold at your own percentage usage but google have this on per month quota.
Try not to put it on server and delete it once used or create some sort of key rotation mechanism.

Comment: This used to be possible with AppEngine, where you could set a hard spending cap per day. This functionality is being removed however, so I doubt there is a plan for supporting this use case.

Answer (score 0):

As per Link [1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas#request_quotas) there is no Hard quota limit for Vision API on a monthly basis . If you need to use this feature you can request for this feature using the link [2](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

In the meantime or as workaround you can control your vision API budget by using the Cloud Billing Budget API by following the link [3](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#budget-amount).